# Find out what repositories are available with Tortoise HG?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I run mercurial-server to host hg repositories.  I have a windows machine with tortoise hg.  Is there any way for tortoise hg to connect to the server to query what repositories are available?

The most common use case when I a priori know the exact repository path is already covered.  I'm thinking about sometimes when I don't know exactly which repository something is in and I want to explore.

Answer (score 0):

Zeroconf extension on both sides

> Zeroconf-enabled repositories will be announced in a network without
>   the need to configure a server or a service. They can be discovered
>   without knowing their actual IP address.
>
> You can discover Zeroconf-enabled repositories by running `hg paths`:
>
> ```
> $ hg paths
> zc-test = http://example.com:8000/test
> ```